# Leaflet popupopen event does not fire if I click directly on another marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Leaflet version 1.3.4

```
map.on('popupopen', function() {
    var marker_id = $("#marker_id ").val();
});
```

- When I click on the first marker to open his popup: popupopen event fire (marker_id = marker_1)
- When I close the first popup with the little cross and I click on the second marker to open his popup: popupopen event fire (marker_id = marker_2)
- But when I click directly on the second marker without close the first popup: popupopen event does not fire (marker_id = marker_1)

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Thanks !

Comment: The question is confusing: the issue in the title cannot be reproduced (e.g. see https://plnkr.co/edit/z5T3tDuodH3jzLem ) and the issue seems to involve the value of a DOM element with `#marker_id` ID with no clue on how (nor why nor when) the value of that element is updated; this leads me to think the issue is really about an unseen race condition, but there's not enough code to investigate/explain the sequence of fired events and value updates.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the marker_id like that:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {        
    var marker_id = e.popup._source.feature.properties.marker_id ;
});
```